# How to change value of a UITextfield on a UIButton click?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uibutton, uitextfield

I have two text fields and a button on my view.

In the first text field, user enters some value in celsius and by clicking on the button,  user is able to find the fahrenheit value on the other textfield. This works fine.

However, when user enters another celsius value in the first textfield, at the touch of the button the fahrenheit value is **APPENDED** to the previous fahrenheit value, instead of changed.

Comment: Any code? How are you setting the text?

Comment: very sorry for incomplete question & the inconvience.i was using a string(soap results) to hold value frm soap request.i was setting string as:  -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
NSLog(@"the value of soap result final is as : %@",soapResults);
    [txtfrnht setText:soapResults];
        
}.So actually i have to set nil for intermediate string on button click like:-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(id) sender
{
    soapResults=nil;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your button action function

```
 farenheitTextField.text=nil;

[farenheitTextField setClearsOnBeginEditing:YES];

 farenheitTextField.text=@"your calculated value";
```

Comment: nil worked for me as setting the string value on button click.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this...u need to call this method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
return YES;
}
```

Also u need to set the previous value of ur 2nd textfield to nil in the Button Action.

Comment: you need to implement with above method.

Answer (score 1):

On button click event just write `text2.text = @"";`
and after that write your entire code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value of the textField to `@""` before you assign the new value. All this on the IBAction method.

Comment: I speak of the value. The way to do it is irrelevant.

Comment: You are missing the point Joze. "" is a string, and this will not compile. The person you are speaking to may not be as knowledgeable about the implementations underneath Objective-C, so maybe you should consider being as didactive as possible. Just a thought, but of course, you do as you please ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this on button click event:

`textField.text = @"YourString";`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use  the delegates function of textfield and just assign a empty NSString to your NSString that contains the value of the first textfield.

As in: `nsstring *demoStr = @"";`

Now it will pick the fresh value each time .